# flutter_stripe example app has 18 errors all "Object is of type 'unknown'." for 'error' variables

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to run flutter_stripe's [example app](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example). I forked and cloned the Github repository to my laptop.

Starting the yarn server results in 18 errors. All start with `Object is of type 'unknown'`. All are `error` or `e` or `err`, on lines 130, 301, 442, 450, 451, 455, 456, 464, 578, 586, 587, 591, 592, 595, 599, and 600. Then it says `Command failed with exit code 2`.

Is this a null safety issue? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your existing [github issue](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/567) with the library maintainers is likely to be your best source of help, however reading that I noticed you said:

> In the last step, setting up server/.env, my Stripe account has pk_test and a pk_live Publishable and Secret Keys. My guess is that I should use the pk_test keys in server/.env.example. Let’s make this clear in the comment at the top of server/.env.example.

This seems to be a misunderstanding of your [Stripe API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys). There are *secret*  keys (`sk_`) for your server and *publishable* keys (`pk_`) for your client-side application as a matching pair, and there is a pair for each of live and test mode. You need to use a matching secret and publishable key [from your dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys).

Additionally, when setting up secrets in environment files, you'll typically be creating a `.env` file in the server/repo root directory. I read the above as though you might be trying to set up your keys in the `.env.example` file which I don't expect would work. You should check with the developer of the library/example about this if `.env` doesn't work.